# Serialize in Java then deserialize in C++?

Tags: java, c++

I have a java program that will send(over TCP) packets to a c++ program. Only two types of objects will be sent (struct A or struct B). I need to serialize the two objects and send them to the c++ program, such that when de-serialized inside the c++ program they will be of the type struct A or struct B, depending on what has been sent. How can I achieve this without any external java packages?

```
            struct A
            {
                unsigned int field1; 
                unsigned int field2; 
            }

            struct B
            {
                unsigned int length;
                struct A list[GLOBALLENGTH];
            }
```

GLOBALLENGTH is a static and globel int.

Please note that I dont need a general solution, as I will strictly be dealing with the mentioned types above. Also, I dont have access to the c++ program(it is a blackbox), both operate in little indian.

Comment: You could use XML, or some magic binary format. What are you going to do about endianness?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I dont have access to the c++ program(it is a blackbox), both operate in little indian.

Comment: Also note that that's an invalid C++ struct. Is it possible that you intended for that to be a `std::vector`, or a pointer?

Comment: JSON is a good format, and is perfectly capable of encoding this.

Comment: If you don't have access to the C++ program, then your solution is dictated by the format that the C++ program accepts.

Comment: If you don't have access to the c++ program, then do you know the specific data format it expects to see?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII typo, fixed now.

Comment: @Martin yes, I have mentioned that in the question. The c++ program expects to see type A or type B only!

Comment: @Mike G: this doesn't really explain what Martin mentioned. If the c++ program can't be touched and you know how it interprets data, then just encode it that way...

Comment: @JanDvorak I cant use external libraries and the c++ program wont "know" it is json. I dont have access to the c++ program

Comment: @leo that is what I am asking for, how can I encode it that way, can you please show some code.

Comment: @MikeG if you can't choose what the program expects, then you have to conform to whatever the program chooses.

Comment: This also means the protocol should be described somewhere and you need to read it.

Comment: @MikeG how do you expect *me* to show you code that will encode data on the *blackbox* format *your* c++ program expects to read (I'm not yelling, just emphasizing)

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, I will need to encode it in my java program such that it conform to the two types above, Im just not sure how to encode them.

Comment: "type A or type B only" doesn't specify what the c++ program expects to see. What byte sequence does the program expect to see for a type A object? For a type B object? If you have the specification of what it expects to see (including any type tag data) then you can write Java code to produce that. Without that information, the task is basically impossible.

Comment: @leo what I meant was, how do you encode them from the java program such that when it is received by the c++ the binary will represent one of the two types.

Comment: I will _guess_ that the application specifies which of the two structs it expects, and you only need to send the _data_ in binary format, raw and without any metadata.

Comment: @TedHopp The C++ program will identify which type it is by checking the length(byte size). Both types have different sizes.

Comment: @MikeG TCP does not respect the packet boundaries.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes!, that would also work. Basically the c++ program will check the size of the raw data in bytes and then classify which type it is. Im not sure how to encode the types in raw data.

Comment: @MikeG you need to use the encoding that the application defines.

Comment: If the application always knows what struct will follow then _most likely_ you shouldn't send that metadata.

Comment: @JanDvorak Again, the two types mentioned above are specified by the appliecation(c++ app).

Comment: @MikeG Did I claim otherwise?

Comment: @JanDvorak "you need to use the encoding that the application defines." that is my question, how do I encode such type in Java?

Comment: @MikeG if you tell us what the application expects, we can tell you how to send it. Does it expect raw binary data? In what order, top to bottom? In what endianness? Once you know this (we don't), it's relatively easy to pack this into the TCP channel.

Comment: @JanDvorak I believe I have misunderstood. Yes, raw binary, in little Indian and bottom-up order.

Comment: @MikeG then see Ted Hopp's answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes! this is what I am looking for. Thanks for being patient. I'm not sure why people are down rating this question, but thanks!

Comment: How big is an int?  How are the fields aligned?

Comment: @MikeG that's because the question should be answerable as-is (how do I encode this protocol in Java: [[definition]], not require a discussion this long (can you choose the protocol? If not, then what the protocol is? ...)

Comment: It wasn't clear that the protocol is given (or if there should be anything else beside raw data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the c++ program expects a raw dump of the data in each structure, with no padding, in little-endian order, with the fields in the declared order, using 32-bit integers. If all that's right, here's one way to write bytes for consumption by the c++ program:

```
private static final int A_SIZE = 8;
private static final int B_SIZE = 4 + GLOBALLENGTH * 8;

public byte[] writeA(A a) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[A_SIZE];
    writeA(a, bytes, 0);
    return bytes;
}

private void writeA(A a, byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, offset, A_SIZE);
    buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buff.putInt(a.field1).putInt(a.field2);
}

public byte[] writeB(B b) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[B_SIZE];
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, 4);
    buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buff.putInt(b.length);
    int offset = 4;
    for (A a : b.list) {
        writeA(a, bytes, offset);
        offset += A_SIZE;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

You can then call the appropriate public method (`writeA(A)` or `writeB(B)`) and send the bytes to the server.

Comment: While an admirable attempt, you're trying to answer an impossible question.  We don't know anything about the layout in this black-box.  How big is an int?  Do we need to consider alignment issues?

Comment: I would think the application expects big-endian (network order)

Comment: @JanDvorak - OP said in a comment that the c++ program is using little-endian.

Comment: @Martin int is typically 32 bits. You are right this is not always true.

Comment: @TedHopp even if the application uses little-endian internally, it could convert to big-endian for the networking purposes.

Comment: @JanDvorak - OP made a big point about the c++ program being a black box. The little-endian comment must therefore be about its external behavior. (Of course, this assumes that OP's comments are accurate as far as they go.)

Answer (score 1):

The serialization algorithm used by Java is standard as far as the Java language is concerned; you cannot deserialize such objects from within a C/C++ program, unless you use an external C/C++ library for the purpose.

The opposite is also true: you can't deserialize C/C++-serialized objects into Java, unless you use an external package of some sort.

Your best bet is, then, to come up with your own protocol and serialize according to it. You'll have to write Java and C/C++ implementations for your protocol.

Comment: There are plenty of standard protocols (XML, JSON, JSON.gzip ...). Why not recommend one of them?

Comment: I would also suggest Google Protocol Buffers if performance was a constraint.

Comment: @JanDvorak, XML is not a protocol. Nor is JSON. At least not according to my definition of "protocol". XML, JSON and such are means to represent arbitrary data; the OP would have to create his own protocol *based* on XML, JSON and so forth.